# どのようにAndroid StudioのIDEメモリを増やすには？

Tags: android, android-studio

最近私はいくつかのプロジェクトを開発しており、IDE Android Studioの読み込みと起動に時間がかかりすぎることに気付きました。

その後、私はIDEのAndroidスタジオのメモリを増やす方法、不思議ですか？

IDEをより速く開始し、結果としてより速く開発するには...

Answer (score 1):

デフォルトで、Android Studio の最大ヒープサイズは 1,280 MB です。
最大ヒープサイズを変更するには、以下の手順に従います。

[Help] > [Edit Custom VM Options] の順にクリックして独自の studio.vmoptions ファイルを開きます。
studio.vmoptions ファイルに行を追加し、-XmxheapSize という構文を使用して最大ヒープサイズを設定します。指定するサイズは、プロジェクトおよびマシン上の使用可能な RAM のサイズに基づいて決定してください。次の行では最大ヒープサイズを 2 GB に設定しています。
-Xmx2g
変更した studio.vmoptions ファイルを保存し、Android Studio を再起動して変更を有効にします。
新しい最大ヒープサイズを確認するには、コマンドプロンプトを起動して、次のコマンドを入力します。
jps -lvm

ソース↓
[Android Studio Settings](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html)